# In Pandas with Groupby: assign a value from a column conditioned on another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col0': list('aabb'), 
                   'col1': np.arange(4),
                   'col2': list('wxyz'),
                   'col3': np.nan})

    col0 col1 col2 col3
0   a    0    w    NaN
1   a    1    x    NaN
2   b    2    y    NaN
3   b    3    z    NaN
```

I want to assign to 'col3' the value of 'col2' corresponding to the minimum value of 'col1', grouped by 'col0'. Expected output:

```
    col0 col1 col2 col3
0   a    0    w    w
1   a    1    x    w
2   b    2    y    y
3   b    3    z    y
```

If grouping by 'col0' was not needed, this would work:

```
df['col3'] = df[df['col1']==df['col1'].min()]['col2'].iloc[0]

    col0 col1 col2 col3
0   a    0    w    w
1   a    1    x    w
2   b    2    y    w
3   b    3    z    w
```

Similarly, this is my try using groupby/apply, which doesn't work as expected:

```
df['col3'] = df.groupby('col0').apply(lambda x: x[x['col1']==x['col1'].min()]['col2'].iloc[0])

    col0 col1 col2 col3
0   a    0    w    NaN
1   a    1    x    NaN
2   b    2    y    NaN
3   b    3    z    NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another `transform`ing with `idxmin` and `loc`:

```
df["col3"] = df.groupby("col0").col1.transform(lambda x: df.loc[x.idxmin(), "col2"])
```

to get

```
  col0  col1 col2 col3
0    a     0    w    w
1    a     1    x    w
2    b     2    y    y
3    b     3    z    y
```

Comment: Ok, mine is the worst and yours is the best :)

Comment: @Stryder I strongly disagree `:)`

Comment: This works perfectly for the special case in which I'm looking for the index of the min value in col1. What if I have a more general condition as: "assign to 'col3' the value of 'col2' corresponding to **a true condition** of 'col1', grouped by 'col0'"?

Comment: @makpalan I'm not sure what you mean by a *true condition*, but perhaps it could also be put in `loc` above instead of `idxmin`. Can you please elaborate on the condition along with some sample input/output (by editing the question)? If that would make this current question very different, then you might opt for asking another one, but if it is close enough perhaps it is fine, thanks.

Comment: @MustafaAydın say I wanted for col3 the (first) value of col2 where col1>0 (a different condition than min value, even if trivial here), then I found this: `df["col3"] = df.groupby("col0").col1.transform(lambda x: df.loc[x.index[x>0].tolist()[0], 'col2'])`. Following your approach is actually possible to get something more general, which is actually what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can use groupby.apply to get a series and then merge it into the df

```
df
  col0  col1 col2
0    a     0    w
1    a     1    x
2    b     2    y
3    b     3    z

col3 = df.groupby("col0").apply(lambda x: x.loc[x["col1"].idxmin(), "col2"])
col3.name = "col3"
df = df.merge(col3, how="left", left_on= "col0", right_index= True)

df
 col0  col1 col2 col3
0    a     0    w    w
1    a     1    x    w
2    b     2    y    y
3    b     3    z    y
```

Answer (score 1):

you can groupby with transform `idxmin` and then `series.map`:

```
d = dict(zip(df['col1'],df['col2']))
df['col3'] = df['col3'].fillna(df.groupby("col0")['col1'].transform('idxmin').map(d))
```

---

```
print(df)

  col0  col1 col2 col3
0    a     0    w    w
1    a     1    x    w
2    b     2    y    y
3    b     3    z    y
```